# issue making Windows slave (Java 7) connect to Linux master (Java 8)

Tags: networking, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson, hudson-api

Facing issue making windows slave connect to Linux master. Linux master is on Java 8 and windows slave is on java 7.  I tried connecting via launching slave agent on slave machine, it shows connected for a second but next second it says terminated.

On Connecting from console, below are the logs :

```
C:\Jenkins>java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://192.168.172.249:8080/jenkins/comp
uter/192.168.172.133ReconTomcatServer/slave-agent.jnlp

Jun 26, 2017 11:41:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up slave: 192.168.172.133ReconTomcatServer

Jun 26, 2017 11:41:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.

Jun 26, 2017 11:41:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://192.168.172.249:8080/jenkins/]

Jun 26, 2017 11:41:55 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpointResolver
 resolve
INFO: Remoting server accepts the following protocols: [JNLP-connect, CLI2-conne
ct, Ping, CLI-connect, JNLP4-connect, JNLP2-connect]

Jun 26, 2017 11:41:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: 192.168.172.249
  Agent port:    41231
  Identity:      0a:71:17:09:ae:dc:64:9a:d4:55:ba:c7:c6:43:4a:2c

Jun 26, 2017 11:41:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking

Jun 26, 2017 11:41:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to 192.168.172.249:41231

Jun 26, 2017 11:41:55 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP4-connect

Jun 26, 2017 11:42:01 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Remote identity confirmed: 0a:71:17:09:ae:dc:64:9a:d4:55:ba:c7:c6:43:4a:2c


Jun 26, 2017 11:42:01 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected

Jun 26, 2017 11:42:02 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
```

Is there any thing I can check.

Followed all steps given in below link:
[Showing exception while connecting slave to master using headless jnlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688744/showing-exception-while-connecting-slave-to-master-using-headless-jnlp/44754044#44754044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was happening due to java version difference.